# How to simplify the code below

Tags: unity

I want to create 9 resistor and each resistor have 4 color code. I use a single array with size 36 to create the color code as below

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AdvanceWayPoint : MonoBehaviour
   {

public Transform player;
public bool CreateResistor;
int RandNum;
public GameObject myprefab;
public GameObject FloatingText;
public GameObject[] Resistor;
public GameObject[] way1;
Vector3[] ExactResistorSpawnPoint;
public int[] ResistorBand;
public float[] ResistorValue;
public float ChoosenResistorValue;
public int Ammo;

void Start()
{
    ResistorBand = new int[36];
    ResistorValue = new float[9];
    Random.InitState(System.DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
    CreateResistor = true;
    player = new GameObject().transform;
    ExactResistorSpawnPoint = new Vector3[9];
}

void Update()
{

    if (CreateResistor == true)
    {
        RandNum = 1;
        CreateResistor = false;
        Waypoint();
    }
    
}

public void Waypoint()
{
    Vector3 SpawnPosition = player.transform.position;
    Vector3 ExactSpawnPoint = new Vector3(SpawnPosition.x + Random.Range(1, 4), 0, SpawnPosition.z + Random.Range(1, 4));
     

    if (RandNum == 1)
    {
        int i = 0;
        int y = 0;
        while (i < 35)
        {
            ExactResistorSpawnPoint[y] = new Vector3(ExactSpawnPoint.x + Random.Range(1, 10), ExactSpawnPoint.y + 7, ExactSpawnPoint.z + Random.Range(1, 10));
            ResistorBand[i] = Random.Range(1, 10);
            ResistorBand[i+1] = Random.Range(1, 10);
            while(ResistorBand[i+1]==ResistorBand[i])
            {
                ResistorBand[i + 1] = Random.Range(1, 10);
            }
            ResistorBand[i+2] = Random.Range(1, 5);
            while(ResistorBand[i + 2]==ResistorBand[i+1]||ResistorBand[i+2]==ResistorBand[i])
            {
                ResistorBand[i + 2] = Random.Range(1,5);
            }
            ResistorBand[i + 3] = Random.Range(1, 3);
            ResistorValue[y] = ((ResistorBand[i] * 10 + ResistorBand[i+1]) * Mathf.Pow(10, ResistorBand[i+2]) / 1000);
            i = i + 4;
            y = y + 1;                     
        }            
        way1 = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("1K ohm");
        if (way1.Length == 0)
        {
            for (y = 0; y < 9; y++)
            {                   
                Instantiate(Resistor[y], ExactResistorSpawnPoint[y], Quaternion.identity);                                  
            }
            
        }
        int RandomChooseWayPointValue = Random.Range(0, 9);
        ChoosenResistorValue = ResistorValue[RandomChooseWayPointValue];
        Instantiate(myprefab, ExactSpawnPoint, Quaternion.identity);
        GameObject go = Instantiate(FloatingText, ExactSpawnPoint, Quaternion.identity);
        go.GetComponent<TextMesh>().text = ResistorValue[RandomChooseWayPointValue].ToString() + " K ohm +/-" + ResistorBand[((RandomChooseWayPointValue+1)*4)-1].ToString() + "%";
    }
}
```

}

In game, I would need to pick up a resistor to a waypoint and each resistor is attached a script "ReadResistor" to retrieve the value of "ResistorValue".

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ReadResistor1 : MonoBehaviour
{
public GameObject ReadValue;
public float value;
public GameObject ResistorPosition;

void Awake()
{
    ReadValue = GameObject.Find("Cube");
    AdvanceWayPoint way = ReadValue.GetComponent<AdvanceWayPoint>();
    value = way.ResistorValue[1];
}

private void OnMouseDrag()
{
     
    Vector3 result = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, 1f));
    transform.position = result;
}
```

}

Since each resistor have to retrieve respective stored value in ResistorValue in "AdvanceWaypoint" script, the current ineffective way I figured out is to create 9 ReadResistor script and attach a script to each of the resistor starting from ReadResistor to ReadResistor8. Since on the awake method, each resistor need to retrieve different array location.

As an example, the 1st resistor would refer to ResistorValue[0] in the awake method,

```
void Awake()
{
  ReadValue = GameObject.Find("Cube");
  AdvanceWayPoint way = ReadValue.GetComponent<AdvanceWayPoint>();
  value = way.ResistorValue[0];
}
```

the second would refer to ResistorValue[1] and so on

```
void Awake()
  {
    ReadValue = GameObject.Find("Cube");
    AdvanceWayPoint way = ReadValue.GetComponent<AdvanceWayPoint>();
    value = way.ResistorValue[1];
  }
```

Is there a way to create a single script for all the 9 resistor but each of them able to retrieve value in different array number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply create a public variable (say `Num` for instance) and then set it via inspector for each resistor:

```cs
public int Num;

void Awake()
  {
    ReadValue = GameObject.Find("Cube");
    AdvanceWayPoint way = ReadValue.GetComponent<AdvanceWayPoint>();
    value = way.ResistorValue[Num];
  }
```

some notes:

- I would recommend using `Start` for this, but this depends on your need (awake runs even if the game object is disabled which may not be desirable for you)
- If you don't have any other uses for `way` then you can combine it with the next line:

```cs
value = ReadValue.GetComponent<AdvanceWayPoint>().ResistorValue[Num];
```

- You can make `Num` private like this: `[Serializable] private int Num`
- Instead of an array with size 36 you can create a struct and then create an array from it:

```cs
public List<ResistorInfo> ResistorBand;

// ...

struct ResistorInfo
{
    public int a;
    public int b;
    public int c;
    public int d;
}
```